# how to prove $f(x)= x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, epsilon-delta

Question is

> > $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{N}$

I know $f$ is uniformly continuous on bounded set because $\delta$ can be found easily from $|x^2-y^2|=|x-y||x+y|<||x|+|y|||x-y|<2C|x-y|$ for some positive number $C$

but if $Domf$ is $\mathbb{N}$, how can I find $\delta$?

Comment: Do you mean on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @SRX That is in fact not true.

Comment: no, in my book, there is written "on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE I know it is not true, but I still the question is weird. If the question has no problem and the answer below is what we expected, then not only the domain is changed but also the topology. Probably $\epsilon-\delta$ is not the best answer then.

Comment: Uniform continuity works on $\Bbb N$ since the topology $\Bbb N$ inherits from $\Bbb R$ is *discrete*; this is in fact the essence of Michaels answer below, methinks.  Cheers!

Comment: Not just discrete but, in a sense, uniformly discrete.  (If the domain had consisted of, say, the square roots of the natural numbers, then the topology would still be discrete, but the function would no longer be uniformly continuous.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any $\epsilon$, let $\delta=1/2$.  Then whenever $|x-y|<1/2$, then $x=y$, so $|x^2-y^2|<\epsilon$